# File only visible to cygwin, not windows?

Tags: windows, java, cygwin

**Problem:**

We have a file created with keytool (from jdk 1.5) that is only visible with the **ls** command. When we do a **dir**, it's not there.

**Specifics:**

- This file is owned by the user, all other files in the folder are owned by system.
- The user is an administrator.
- Hidden files and system files are set to visible in the explorer settings.
- The file was created using the descriptions here: http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html

  > $ keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000

**Output from `dir` command:**

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_22\bin>dir
 Volume in drive C is System
 Volume Serial Number is C0CC-F06B

 Directory of C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_22\bin

2010-12-06  11:26    <DIR>          .
2010-12-06  11:26    <DIR>          ..
2009-10-09  02:36            53 370 appletviewer.exe
2009-10-09  02:36            53 359 apt.exe
2009-10-09  03:16            36 975 beanreg.dll
2009-10-09  02:36            53 368 extcheck.exe
2009-10-09  03:01            20 480 HtmlConverter.exe
2009-10-09  02:36            53 370 idlj.exe
2009-10-09  02:36            53 351 jar.exe
[...(files omitted)...]
2009-10-09  02:36            53 392 tnameserv.exe
2009-10-09  02:36           127 101 unpack200.exe
              36 File(s)      2 039 866 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  12 419 006 464 bytes free
```

**Output from cygwin `ls` command:**

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_22\bin>ls -l
total 2132
-rwx------+ 1 SYSTEM   SYSTEM        20480 Oct  9  2009 HtmlConverter.exe
-rwx------+ 1 SYSTEM   SYSTEM        53370 Oct  9  2009 appletviewer.exe
-rwx------+ 1 SYSTEM   SYSTEM        53359 Oct  9  2009 apt.exe
-rwx------+ 1 SYSTEM   SYSTEM        36975 Oct  9  2009 beanreg.dll
-rwx------+ 1 SYSTEM   SYSTEM        53368 Oct  9  2009 extcheck.exe
-rwx------+ 1 SYSTEM   SYSTEM        53370 Oct  9  2009 idlj.exe
-rwx------+ 1 SYSTEM   SYSTEM        53351 Oct  9  2009 jar.exe
[...(files omitted)...]
-rwx------+ 1 jchan    Domain Users   2207 Mar 14 11:51 key-android.jks
-rwx------+ 1 SYSTEM   SYSTEM        53392 Oct  9  2009 tnameserv.exe
-rwx------+ 1 SYSTEM   SYSTEM       127101 Oct  9  2009 unpack200.exe
```

Note the key-android.jks file that shows in the second listing.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific about how you're verifying things?

Comment: @OliverSalzburg Please see the updated question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Windows Vista/7 the file is not under `C:\Program Files\` but in the Virtualstore blow
`%localappdata%\VirtualStore\`, as normal Users are not allowed to write in 
`C:\Program Files\`. Try to put the keyfile in another directory.

Comment: We found the file in virtualstore. Thank you a lot. :)

Comment: Similar; [Cygwin sees a file that windows can't--I want to access this file from python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18087991)