# File shows up with ls but not with dir

Tags: pdf, mingw

*Windows 7*

I generated a pdf using [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) in `C:/Program Files/wkhtmltopdf/bin` with the command `wkhtmltopdf http://google.co.uk google.pdf` to test it out.

However, `google.pdf` does not show in Windows Explorer and running `ls -l` shows it but running `dir` does not... Why would the file be invisible in this way?

**Edit**

Running `cat google.pdf` prints the pdf to the terminal

I also found I can copy the file to another directory - with exactly the same issues with the copy of the file in its new directory.

Looking at the permissions from `ls -l` - <strike>noone has execute permission for the pdf file. I don't know whether that is important though.</strike> This isn't important - other pdf's on my computer have the same set of permissions.

**Result of `attrib google.pdf` in C:/Program Files/wkhtmltopdf/bin**

```
attrib google.pdf
File not found - google.pdf
```

**Result of `ls -l` in C:/Program Files/wkhtmltopdf/bin**

```
total 64957
-rw-r--r--  1 Admin  Administ   305109 Jul  1 14:59 bbc.pdf
-rw-r--r--  1 Admin  Administ    30426 Jul  1 15:28 google.pdf
-rwxr-xr-x  1 Admin  Administ   489773 Jun 17 10:54 libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll
-rwxr-xr-x  1 Admin  Administ  6762827 Jun 17 10:54 libstdc++-6.dll
-rwxr-xr-x  1 Admin  Administ   243109 Jun 17 10:54 libwinpthread-1.dll
-rwxr-xr-x  1 Admin  Administ 41729536 Jun 17 10:54 wkhtmltoimage.exe
-rwxr-xr-x  1 Admin  Administ 41827328 Jun 17 10:53 wkhtmltopdf.exe
-rwxr-xr-x  1 Admin  Administ 41639424 Jun 17 10:52 wkhtmltox.dll
```

Comment: Are you running both ls and dir against the same location? Where is the file stored? On a file server, or are you copying it from a Linux machine to Windows?

Comment: The file is stored in `C:/Program Files/wkhtmltopdf/bin` - the same directory I am running these commands from. This is all within that folder on my WIndows machine (I have ls and other commands available from my installation of Git for Windows)

Comment: @AdamThompson I've just found that no-one has execute permissions on the pdf (from running `ls -l`). Could that be the problem?

Comment: Is it cygwin ls you're using on Windows, or something else? From the command prompt, can you cd to the directory with the file and run attrib google.pdf, and post the results here, please?

Comment: Could you, please post the output of `ls -l` from inside `C:/Program Files/wkhtmltopdf/bin`

Comment: @AdamThompson Checking the directory of `ls.exe` shows it came from my installation of [Git for Windows](https://msysgit.github.io/), part of msys. @smc, see my edit to the question

Comment: I think I've found the problem. It's UAC virtualisation at work. Presumably the wkhtmltopdf binaries were not compiled with a UAC manifest, so they're getting redirected to the VirtualStore.

Comment: Your question may have been already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20161985/1540660 and here 
http://superuser.com/a/400762/281154

Comment: Thank you, found the files now! Do you know why `ls -l` still showed the file in that directory? Does it scan the area in VirtualStore at the same time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the attributes are set correctly (ie the file is not set as 'hidden' or 'system'), this is probably the result of a non-elevated program attempting to write to the **%ProgramFiles%** structure.

When non-elevated programs attempt to write to this directory structure, they will end up writing to **%LocalAppData%\VirtualStore**.
For example, if the application *unelevated.exe* attempts to write to *C:\Program Files\Unelevated\file.txt*, it will actually write to *C:\Users\Bob\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files\Unelevated\file.txt*.

Other applications may also end up at the VirtualStore location, depending on [how they've been compiled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384608.aspx).

This may or may not be [fixed in later versions of MinGW](http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/feature-requests/53/).

Comment: Thanks! You've saved me a major headache. I don't suppose you know whether the same thing would happen if wkhtmltopdf were installed on a webserver? Thank you once again!

Comment: If the webserver is running Windows Server 2008 or later, it will run the process virtualised. If you mean that the web server would create the file, and the client would download it using a web browser, then it will work just the same as if the web browser was downloading any other file from anywhere else. Best thing to do is to not use the application to write to the %ProgramFiles% structure. Either write the file to your Documents folder, or setup some other folder on your PC/webserver (eg C:\GeneratedPDFs) and write the files to that.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you so much for your help with this!